# PHPStorm correct PHPDoc for a Collection of Strings

Tags: php, laravel, phpdoc

I have this collection and would like to annotate the correct PHPDoc for this collection. Would it be `Collection<string>`?

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#525
  #items: array:3 [
    0 => "string_1"
    1 => "string_2"
    2 => "string_3"
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

Comment: You are correct, `Collection<string>` would be the correct annotation if you are using PHPstorm, you can also use `string[]`, but prefer the first one as the IDE understands it too

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thank you for your comment with the answer! Thanks also for the alternative suggestion `string[]`. Top! Have a nice day!